# Gradient.radial() from the documentation isn't available?

Tags: dart, flutter

### I want to create a gradient shader.

[The `Gradient.radial()` constructor should return one.](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Gradient-class.html)

However, VS Code claims that this *method is not defined for `Gradient`*. huh.

[image: screenshot of the offending lines]

Now, from [what I've seen online](https://medium.com/flutter-community/make-shimmer-effect-in-flutter-dbe7a1bfd980), you can create a `RadialGradient` object and then use `.createShader(rect)` to convert it into a shader <s>(haven't got it work yet, but maybe I'm implementing it wrong)</s>, but that can't be the intended way, right?

### Update:

As @pskink pointed out, I'm using a newer version of Flutter and have to import the [Gradient shader class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Gradient-class.html) as part of the Dart ui library.

The resulting code is valid and looks like this:

```dart
paint.shader = ui.Gradient.radial(
  Offset(-.5, -.5),
  1, // The radius
  List.from({
    Colors.lightBlueAccent,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.deepPurpleAccent},
    growable: false
  )
);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't render anything.

This is how the code with the `.createShader()` method on the [other Gradient class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/Gradient-class.html) looks.

```dart
    RadialGradient _gradient = RadialGradient(
      colors: List.from({
        Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.deepPurpleAccent},
        growable: false),
    );

    // center is the center of the canvas
    paint.shader = _gradient.createShader(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: center,
        radius: size.shortestSide / 2
      )
    );
```

This is kinda ugly IMO (and less efficient?), but it does render the expected result.

### 2nd Update:

When having more than 2 color elements in the Gradient shader class you can't omit the stops. This info is just being presented as an errorlog, which is why I didn't see it. With that being fixed: Both versions return different results...

This code returns this gradient:

```dart
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final paint = Paint();

    RadialGradient _gradient = RadialGradient(
       radius: 1,
       center: Alignment(-.5, -.5),
       tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
       colors: List.from({Colors.lightBlueAccent, Colors.blue, Colors.deepPurpleAccent}, growable: false),
       stops: List.from({0.0, 0.5, 1.0}, growable: false),
     );

     paint.shader = _gradient.createShader(
       Rect.fromCircle(
         center: center,
         radius: size.shortestSide / 2
       )
     );

    canvas.drawCircle(center, size.shortestSide / 2, paint);
  }
```

[image: the first gradient is fucking beautiful]

While this code renders this gradient:

```dart
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    final paint = Paint();

    paint.shader = ui.Gradient.radial(
      Offset(-.5, -.5),
      1, // this is the radius
      List.from({Colors.lightBlueAccent, Colors.blue, Colors.deepPurpleAccent},
          growable: false),
      List.from({0.0, 0.5, 1.0}, growable: false),
      TileMode.clamp,
    );

    canvas.drawCircle(center, size.shortestSide / 2, paint);
  }
```

[image: a purple-grey blob]

Comment: whats the output of `flutter --version`? 1.0.0 or later?

Comment: @pskink `1.4.11-pre.27` I've set my channel to the master branch.

Comment: so maybe your `Gradient` is https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/Gradient-class.html and not https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Gradient-class.html ? try `import 'dart:ui' as ui;` and use `ui.Gradient.Ctrl-space`

Comment: @pskink Hmm, I think this might be it, I don't get any compilation errors with this method, but the gradient also doesn't show up...

Comment: post your current code then

Comment: @pskink not sure if you're getting a notification for the edit, so sorry if you're getting 2 now.
I edited the og post.

Comment: hmm, radius == 1? tired some other value like 100?

Comment: @pskink (I have tried that), but it's correct.
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/RadialGradient/radius.html

And as this RadialGradient class abstracts the UI one, that's probably true for that one too

Comment: `p.shader = ui.Gradient.radial(Offset(100, 100), 400, [Colors.red, Colors.blue]);` works just fine - `RadialGradient` uses [0..1] range because you have to call `createShader()` method on it to create a shader

Comment: @pskink now I feel like an idiot for not trying it out with a **much** bigger number.
size.longestSize is just perfect for my usage.

So - what's better? Do you know of any performance benefits by using the shader directly?

Comment: i have no idea but... i remember that one form had a lot of bugs but... i have no idea if it was `RadialGradient` or `Gradient.radial` ;-(